# NuGet force install ignoring version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

NPM guy, not familiar to NuGet thing.

I try to

```
  Install-Package UnmanagedExports
```

but,

```
Installing 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.6'.
Successfully installed 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.6'.
Adding 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.6' to my-project.
Uninstalling 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.6'.
Successfully uninstalled 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.6'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install

Install-Package : Could not install package 'UnmanagedExports 1.2.6'. You are trying to install this package 
into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references 
or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.


   At line:1 char:2
    +  Install-Package UnmanagedExports 
    +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Probably this library simply don't catch up to indicate the latest .net version, I hope so, therefore I will force to install.

Can you tell me how?

I unzipped the `nupkg`, and investigated the contents but no clue. Thanks.

sdfsd

Answer (score 0):

Ok, version mess. I am using VS.net 2012 now. 
VS.net 2010 express does not support nuget, generally.